# How many distinct equilateral triangles can be formed in a regular nonagon having atleast two of their vertices as the vertices of nonagon.

Tags: combinatorics

As the question says two vertices are common
so, I did **$^9C_2=36$** but after that i am not able to proceed further.
how should I think?

Comment: As I noted in my question, and accentuated by a comment there by Christian Blatter, there is ambiguity in the question. Does "two of their vertices" mean "at least two" or "precisely two", in other words are triangles with three vertices in common with the nonagon counted? And for the case of exactly two vertices, does "formed in the nonagon" mean that the third vertex must be in the interior of the nonagon? Please make this clear.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes question has ambiguities 
it should be atleast 2 vertices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple using a simplified* form of inclusion-exclusion. There are $\binom92=36$ chords in the $9$-gon, each giving two distinct equilateral triangles, for $72$ in all. But some triangles are counted more than once; it is not hard to see that if two side of such a triangle are chords, the third one is as well, and the vertices then are regularly spaced at distance $3$ around the $9$-gon. This gives $3$ triangles that are over-counted, namely $3$ times each; total over-counting $3\times(3-1)=6$, so $72-6=66$ triangles in all.

By the way, I am reading "having two of their vertices..." as a minimal requirement; if you want to insist on *exactly* two vertices, then the $3$ special triangles should not be counted at all, so you should correct by $3\times3=9$ rather than by $6$.

*This is simplified because we can get a direct measure of the over-counting being done. Normally one would enumerate all pairs of initial data that produce the same result and compensate for that, then all triples that thus lead to over-compensation, correcting for them, and so forth. But here that seems unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: The triangles are supposed to be "in the nonagon".

Answer (score 2):

There are less triangles than you think. There are also equilateral triangles with all vertices on the nonagon vertices. It should be declared how these triangles are counted.

[image]